# Dynamicaly build search query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have table `tblLocation` which stores data in following way

```
LocationID      |PropertyName        |PropertyValue
------------------------------------------------
1               |Type                |City
1               |Name                |Los Angeles
1               |State               |California
1               |PopulationDensity   |8092
2               |Type                |City
2               |Name                |Houstan
2               |State               |Texas    
2               |PopulationDensity   |3501
```

The front end application sent the search criteria in following format to the stored procedure.

```
{{@@State!!<Equals>##California??}[OR]{@@State!!<Equals>##Texas??}}[AND]{@@PopulationDensity!!<Greater Than>##3000??}
```

Currently above string is parsed and dynamic sql statement is created in the stored procedure.

Is there any better way to do this without using dynamic sql? I cannot change the input format to the stored procedure.

Comment: Because it looks like the conditions are user defined, dynamic sql is probably the best bet, otherwise you'd have a bear of a statement taking every option into account, which could degrade performance significantly.

Comment: EAV with a fixed set of attributes is the worst kind of EAV

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help but I can only offer my condolences. unless you suffer from very bad performance or high danger of sql injection attacks, you should probably stick with what you've got working now.